# PHP router: HTTP-Header in css-file

Tags: php, http-headers

### PHP-server without router (working)

```
$ php -S 127.0.0.1:8000
PHP 5.6.15 Development Server started at Sat Nov 21 13:12:04 2015
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:8000
```

Header of style.css:

```
$ curl -I http://127.0.0.1:8000/style.css
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Host: 127.0.0.1:8000
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/css; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 23
```

Content of style.css (via Chrome Inspector, Preview):

```
body{background:#fff;}
```

### PHP-server with router (not working)

```
$ php -S 127.0.0.1:8001 router.php
PHP 5.6.15 Development Server started at Sat Nov 21 13:15:02 2015
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:8001
```

Header of style.css:

```
$ curl -I http://127.0.0.1:8001/style.css
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Host: 127.0.0.1:8001
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/css; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 23
```

Content of style.css (via Chrome Inspector, Preview) - **problem**:

```
�HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Host: 127.0.0.1:8000
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/css; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 23

body{background:#fff;}
```

**Content of router.php**

```
<?php return false; ?>
```

Why is the HTTP-header written to the top of style.css?

Comment: Strange. I cannot reproduce with the same PHP version. Chrome returns the correct content with the expected length 23.

Comment: Sorry, the content-length is not the problem. It´s in both cases 23 (i edited the question). The problem is the HTTP-header and the special-character inside the http-response (content) of style.css.

Comment: I did understand that. Can you check what the non-printable character is in a hex editor?

Comment: I did a bit of research and found that 1f 8b 08 may indicate a gz file header, but as far as I know the built-in PHP web server isn't capable of serving with gzip compression https://digital-forensics.sans.org/media/hex_file_and_regex_cheat_sheet.pdf

Comment: Thanks, you pointed me to the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

### Update: Solution

Set the following value in php.ini:

```
zlib.output_compression = off
```